# In "X-Men Origins: Wolverine", why didn't Zero use adamantium bullets?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine

In the scene in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* where Wolverine has the adamantium bonded with his skeleton, after Wolverine escaped the operating room,  Col. Striker ordered Zero (an expert marksman) to shoot Wolverine and kill him. After Zero left, Striker got a gun and Adamantium bullets.

Wouldn't it be smarter to give the adamantium bullets to Zero before issuing out the shoot to kill order, instead of keeping it for himself as a last card? Zero could even kill Wolverine with that bullet in both sides of his brain, saving them the trouble of frying his brain.

Why did Striker not give the adamantium bullets to Zero, before letting him chase Logan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought they were mostly trying to catch him still. I didn't think that bullets could kill Wolverine, even before he got the adamantium. If he could die in a hail of gun fire, it is doubtful he would have lived through the wars montage, or the firing squad scene. If I correctly recall the scene where Stryker tells Zero to kill him, Stryker was either knowingly sending Zero to his death, or this was simply a flaw in the script.

Comment: might be. But i dont know whats the effort of zero trying to kill wolverine now he has adamantium bones. the doctor who gave the adamantium bullets to stryker said, that these bullets could only penetrate his skull. (it might not kill him but i will wipe out his memory) so given that idea, If I am stryker, I would definitely give it to Zero. Stryker gave wolverine an armor, Zero got a stick instead of a sharp sword. Zero's wolverine-hunt was pointless.

Answer (score 5):

I don't recall the caliber of the guns/rifles being used, perhaps there weren't any suitable for Zero's weaponry. I think an expert might not like to use bullets he may have never fired before and so be unfamiliar with the load/flight etc.

Comment: I agree. There were only a limited number of bullets and one gun that seemed custom built to fire them. If I were Stryker, I wouldn't part with it while there was an indestructible man on the loose.

Comment: It was done in a comic (don't remember which one) in which an adamantium gun was used. It was made of titanium and some other special parts. Honestly BS, as though Admantium might be an unbreakable metal, it's not like the gunpowder would be that much more powerful. I don't know the density of it, but gold bullets and DU rounds have been fired using modern-day gunpowder, and the gun was exactly the same.